# Syncing with Google Calendar changes time of new items

Tags: 8.0, calendars

I have Lumia 520 with WP8. I am using two calendars - Google and Exchange. I am in GMT+1 time zone and have this zone set everywhere (phone, Google, Exchange). We observe daylight saving. In summer time everything worked fine. When time switched to winter time all items I create on the phone in google calender change it's time by one hour (they start one hour sooner than inteded). It shows correct time for appx. 30 seconds and then it changes (I guess change happens after sync). Exchange calendar works fine. If I create item via web on Google Calendar it syncs fine and no change happens. Any ideas what's wrong and how to fix it?

Comment: Haven't seen this issue with my 1020 which syncs up with my Work Gmail/Calendar. Maybe something option setting wise in Gmail?

Comment: I've had the same problem since daylight saving changed, I believe. I'm also on GMT+1. WP8, Nokia Lumia 920. Only a problem when synching Google Calendar the phone. Adding an appointment in the Google Calendar web view syncs correctly to my phone. Adding one from the phone moves it back one hour right after adding it.  
The problem is reported on other forums as well 
http://productforums.google.com/forum/m/#!topic/google-education/ZDqRvvjxsBI  
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/a4218246-45f4-4772-acde-157056c8672e/bug-calendar-google-and-time?forum=winphoneosissues